# malihu with both horizontal and vertical scroll

Tags: jquery-plugins

I'm using this [scrollbar](http://manos.malihu.gr/jquery-custom-content-scroller/) plugin witch works ok but now I have some new requirements...
So, I'm looking for an alternative to have both horizontal and vertical scrolling at the same time as it seems this does not support it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Enscroll plugin support horizontal scrolling:

**Enscroll:**

http://enscrollplugin.com/